# Parsing arguments in multi-line C-Functions

Tags: c#, c, regex, parsing

I have a few examples of the first line of implementation of C functions that I need to extract the parameters from. For example:

```
double FuncName1(char *testnum, char *hipin_source, char *hipin_sense,
                    char *lopin_source, char *lopin_sense, DMM_ResRange range, float delay) {
```

and

```
double FuncName2(char *testnum, char *hipin, char *lopin, DMM_ResRange range, float delay, bool offset) {
```

Is there any RegEx that I can use in C# to extract function name, return type, but more importantly the arguments?

EDIT:
I am developing in C# and need to parse C-source code files creating objects like Func that has string Name, string ReturnType, List with Arg object having string argType, and string argName

EDIT 2:
Well, I finally tried and it is not working... may be I did not define those right... I am trying to parse a function call that either coded like this:

```
     DCPS_Apply(1,    // Module (optional comment)
           5.0,  // Voltage (optional comment)
           2.0); // Current (optional comment)
```

or like this:

```
     DCPS_Apply(1, 5.0, 2.0); // optional comment
```

and I need function name and the arguments...

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the parameters from"? Are you converting the `C` to `C#`? Also, what does `RegEx` have to do with this?

Comment: This sounds very heavily like a XY Problem. Why would you want this data? Why are you working on sourcecode? Why do you want to sole a issue with native C++ code in C#/.NET?

Comment: what do you mean, *extract arguments*? types, names , or just declaration strings? most likely you will not be able to do it with a regex.

Comment: In general it's non-trivial to parse a C function definition, so a regex solution is unlikely unless you severely limit the input (to some small subset of what C actually allows).

Comment: It's non-trivial to parse any C declaration, not just functions.  ;)  `double (*f) (double (*)(void))(double)` for example is not necessarily impossible to do with RegEx, but it would be very ugly, to say nothing of comments between parameters and things like `__attribute__((unused))` in some compiler-specific code and qualified values, qualified pointers, etc.  You might try doing something with the [AST used by Clang via LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html).  Otherwise, there's always SWIG...?

Comment: @MemReflect I think it is necessarily impossible, since functions that take pointers to functions that take pointers to functions... mean that you'd have to balance nested parentheses, which is well-known to be impossible with just regex.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ah, true enough.  I suppose that's one difference between parsers and RegEx.  I recall someone asking how to deal with XML with RegEx, and the consensus was "Don't do that.  Use an XML parser"  :)

Comment: I am developing in C# and need to parse C- source code creating objects like Func that has Name, ReturnType, List<Arg> with Arg object having argType, and argName.

Comment: I will have only these 2 forms of C-Functions - no others...

Comment: Have you tried writing any regex of your own?

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                @"double FuncName1(char *testnum, char *hipin_source, char *hipin_sense,
                    char *lopin_source, char *lopin_sense, DMM_ResRange range, float delay) { }
                  double FuncName2(char *testnum, char *hipin, char *lopin, DMM_ResRange range, float delay, bool offset) { }
                ";

            string pattern1 = @"(?'type'\w+)\s+(?'name'[^(]+)\((?'parameters'[^)]+)\)";                    
            string pattern2 = @"(?'key'[^\s]+)\s+(?'value'[*\w]+),?";

            MatchCollection matches1 = Regex.Matches(input, pattern1);

            foreach (Match match1 in matches1.Cast<Match>())
            {
                string parameters = match1.Groups["parameters"].Value;
                MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(parameters, pattern2);
                string[] key_value = matches2.Cast<Match>().Select((x, i) => string.Format("Key[{0}] : '{1}', Value[{0}] : '{2}'", i, x.Groups["key"].Value, x.Groups["value"].Value)).ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("Type : '{0}', Name : '{1}', Parameters : '{2}'", match1.Groups["type"].Value, match1.Groups["name"].Value, string.Join(";", key_value));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it shortly. My regex skills are primitive at best...

Comment: Well, I finally tried and it is not working... may be I did not define those right... I am trying to parse a function call that either coded like this:

Comment: Did you look at the results from my inputs?  Are you getting any results from first match?

Comment: The code posted will produce output on the console.  If you are not getting any output then the program is not running or there is something wrong with the console.  Make sure the compiler is not giving any errors.  Put a break point (F11) on first instruction and make sure the code is running.

Comment: I create a simple app and put this code there - it simply does not produce any results - the forach loop is not processing anything since there are no matches for:
         DCPS_Apply(1,    // Module (optional comment)
                               5.0,  // Voltage (optional comment)
                               2.0); // Current (optional comment)

Comment: My code is looking for the return type like double.

Comment: hmmm...The functions that I posted are just examples - it could be any type. I don't think that 'double' should be hard-coded in the regex.... I just need a simple way to recognize function calls and recognize the beginning of the function implementation. Each of these, as we know, can spread over multiple lines...I do realize that it is not an easy exercise - I do not have this regex expertise...

Comment: We can change pattern to this :  @"(?'type'\w+)?\s*(?'name'[^(]+)\((?'parameters'[^)]+)\)"; I made the return type optional by putting a question mark.  Then changed to s from a plus sign (one or more) to an asterisk (zero or more).

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help - I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Still not there. It displays this (sorry but no formatting in comments): Type : 'DCPS_Appl', Name : 'y', Parameters : 'Key[0] : '', Value[0] : '';Key[1] : '', Value[1] : '''
Type : '', Name : '); // Curren', Parameters : 'Key[0] : '', Value[0] : '';Key[1] : '', Value[1] : '''
Type : 'DCPS_Appl', Name : 'y', Parameters : 'Key[0] : '', Value[0] : '';Key[1] : '', Value[1] : ''' So, I am pretty sure it does not take into account that there are comments suffixed on each line and some spaces or tab between the argument and the comment...

Comment: parameters are only between a set of parenthesis.  So code is looking for opening and closing parenthesis and the parameters between the parenthesis.